# Set popup window title for Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm building a browser extension that will work in multiple browsers. When the browser action is clicked, a popup is created displaying the extension's page. Chrome uses the popup page's title tag as the title of the popup window, but Firefox doesn't.

Instead I get the following:

[image]

Why doesn't Firefox use the page title? In an attempt to fix it, I set the window title in the windows.create callback, but that didn't work either.

Here is the background.js script that opens the popup.

```
'use strict';

let browser = (function () {
    return window.msBrowser ||
        window.browser ||
        window.chrome;
})();

var popupWindowId = false;

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    // Open the popup if not already open. If open, focus on it.
    if(popupWindowId === false) {
        popupWindowId = true;
        browser.windows.create({
            'url': 'index.html',
            'type': 'popup',
            'height': 525,
            'width': 350
        }, function(win) {
            win.title = 'My Title';
            popupWindowId = win.id;
            firefoxWorkaroundForBlankPanel();
        });

        return;
    } else if(typeof popupWindowId === 'number'){
        // The window is open, and the user clicked the button.
        // Focus the window.
        browser.windows.update(popupWindowId, { focused: true });
    }
});

browser.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (winId){
    if(popupWindowId === winId){
        popupWindowId = false;
    }
});

// workaround for bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425829
// bug causes popup to appear blank until resized
async function firefoxWorkaroundForBlankPanel () {
    const {id, width, height} = await browser.windows.getCurrent();
    browser.windows.update(id, {
        height: height + 1
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't remove the extension URL from the popup window title. According to this [Mozilla bug report discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296365) this is intentional in order to prevent spoofing/phishing attempts by malicious extensions (e.g. by fooling the user that the extension popup window is part of the browser UI). But at least they are likely to change it to show "Extension [Extension name]" in the window title instead of the ugly extension URL.